# Multiple Inheritance Virtual Call Ambiguity

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

The problem at hand is hard to describe so the code is placed up front for better clarity.

```
struct Base
{
    int b;
    virtual void foo(){cout << b << endl;}
    Base(int x) : b(x){}
};

struct Derived1 : Base    //not virtual
{
    virtual void foo(){/*Derived2's code*/}
    Derived1() : Base(1){}
};

struct Derived2 : Base    //not virtual
{
    virtual void foo(){/*Derived2's code*/}
    Derived2() : Base(2){}
};

struct MultiInheritance : Derived1, Derived2
{
    void bar1()
    {
        //needs to access Derived1's Base foo()
    }
    void bar2()
    {
        //needs to access Derived2's Base foo()
    }
};
```

Suppose that in some weird bizarre scenario, I would want a base class `MultiInheritance` that has two base classes `Derived1` and `Derived2` that have a common **non-virtual** base class `Base`.

There are two `Base` in `MultiInheritance`, how do I specify which `Base` class I wish to access in `MultiInheritance`?

<s>The code above seems to work fine by casting several times, but I'm not sure if this is defined behavior or not. If it is, how is this implemented by the compiler to fulfill the needs of polymorphism? On one hand `virtual` calls should all result in the same `virtual` function table, but on the other if it does it wouldn't output different answers.</s>

**EDIT**

I wish to emphasize that the `Base` classes are required to be **non-virtual**

**EDIT2**

Deep apologies, I seriously misrepresented myself. The code above is updated better reflects my original question.

Comment: Which one do you consider the *correct* `Base`? Or is your question how to make it so that there's only one `Base`?

Comment: Your analysis is correct and the compiler will build a correct vtable reflecting the existence of two base classes. To avoid that, you need virtual inheritance and the vtable structure will become more complex.

Comment: There is no ambiguity in your example, it behaves exactly like it should by the book. "Virtual table" is an implementation detail. Nobody is saying anywhere that each implementation must have one vtbl per class, or that there must be one entry for each function signature in each vtable. In fact it is extremely likely that at least one of the above is incorrect for any implementation that uses vtables.

Comment: Not for nothing this is called "the dreaded diamond of death". Just don't do it. If for some strange reason you feel compelled to shoot yourself in whatever, just say `static_cast<Derived1*>(this)`.

Comment: @n.m. Diamond inheritance isn't intrinsically bad. The problem is unclear semantics with lots of special cases. I've used diamond inheritance in OCaml, and it works just fine, because there's a single simple rule that governs it: last version of an inherited method wins. So if an object inherits classes `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, in that order, and all have a method called `qux`, then the object will have the version of `qux` in `bar`.

Comment: @EduardoLeón "unclear semantics with lots of special cases" If this is not "intrinsically bad" then I don't know what is. "In OCaml" Diamond (and multiple) inheritance in OCaml is nothing like C++. Literally nothing in common.

Comment: @n.m. I explicitly said that "unclear semantics with lots of special cases" is the problem, not diamond inheritance itself. Reread the first two sentences in my previous comment.

Comment: In regards to your Edit 2, the code I listed in my answer below directly does what you are requesting.

Comment: @n.m. How are the semantics unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more illustrative example.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Res, typename Arg>
Res& as(Arg& arg)
{
  return arg;
}

struct Base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : Base {};
struct Derived2 : Base {};

struct MoreDerived1 : Derived1
{
    void foo() { cout << "Derived1\n"; }
};

struct MoreDerived2 : Derived2
{
    void foo() { cout << "Derived2\n"; }
};

struct MultiInheritance : MoreDerived1,  MoreDerived2
{
    void bar1() { as<Derived1>(*this).foo(); }
    void bar2() { as<Derived2>(*this).foo(); }
};

int main ()
{
     MultiInheritance m;
     m.bar1();
     m.bar2();
}
```

This example illustrates that:

1. You don't need to specify which Base you need explicitly using a full inheritance path, it is enough to go down to a subobject that has an unambiguous Base subobject
2. The virtual function mechanism works here. It would not work if you tried to call `Derived1::foo()`.

The `as` helper function is just a syntactic sugar, you could just as well say

```
Derived1& d = *this;
d.foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the diamond problem.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

If you want to keep base non-virtual and get the behavior you are seeking now, you can do this inside MultipleInheritance the following way to ensure you are calling the `foo()` function from the correct base class

```
struct MultiInheritance : Derived1, Derived2
{
    void bar1()
    {
       Derived1::foo();
    }
    void bar2()
    {
        Derived2::foo();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are two Base in MultiInheritance, how do I specify which Base
>   class I wish to access in MultiInheritance?

You have an ambiguity in which base-object you are calling in

```
void MultiInheritance::bar1(){
     foo();
}
```

The way to resolve this is by telling the compiler where to look for foo.

```
void MultiInheritance::bar1(){
     Derived1::foo();  // The same foo() as in your question.
}
```

This is what is accomplished by your

```
void MultiInheritance::bar1()
{
    Derived1& d = *this;
```

This is described in the standard by §10.2.12. This is well defined. As is your chain of

```
void MultiInheritance::bar1()
{
    Derived1& d = *this;
    Base& b = *this;
```

by the same paragraph.

Unfortunately the scope resolution operator can't get you to jump from MultiInhteritance directly to Base as

```
MultiInheritance::foo(){
     Derived1::Base::foo();
```

is describing a *nested* class `Base`.

To get to the foo() belonging to Base you use the scope resolution syntax in MultiInheritance, as well as in Derived1 and Derived2.

```
Derived1()::foo(){
    Base::foo;
```

If this is inappropriate then the option you proposed is the option remaining.

> If it is, how is this implemented by the compiler to fulfill the needs
>   of polymorphism? On one hand virtual calls should all result in the
>   same virtual function table, but on the other if it does it wouldn't
>   output different answers.

Compiler implementations differ by compiler, and as a commenter stated: Using vtables for virtual functions is an implementation detail.  And if an implementation uses a vtable for virtual functions, the implementation need to take this scenario into account.